# Conditional distribution of $X$ given $Y$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

I'm practicing on conditional distribution. This is my exercise

> Suppose that the lifespans of two light bulbs are independent and identically distributed exponential RVs. Let $X$ and $Y$ be the times at which the first and second bulbs burn out, respectively ($X \leq Y$). What is the conditional distribution of $X$ given $Y$.

Can I do something like this: Since $X,Y$ are independent, then $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_X(x).f_Y(y)$. Then $f_{X}(x|y) = \dfrac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)} = f_X(x)$. I think that I must be so wrong about this. Can somebody please help me out.

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are independent then the distribution of $X$ conditioned on $Y$ is the same as the distribution of $X$.

Comment: So my answer is correct?

Comment: Cause I didn't use anything about the exponential distribution. So it's weird to me

Comment: Why are $X$ and $Y$ independent?

Comment: @hxltulane I could ask tell you that Bob has blue hair and George has green hair, independent of each other, and the answer to the question "what colour hair does Bob have" would still be "blue." What's weird about it?

Comment: @Math1000 the problem does *not* specify that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. $X$ is the min of two iid exponential random variables and $Y$ is the max of those same two variables. The underlying variables are independent but $X$ and $Y$ are not.

Comment: @DavidClyde Oh, I misread the question. My bad.

Comment: @DavidClyde right. I now understand the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the lifespans of the bulbs be $A$ and $B$. These are iid exponential RVs. Then $X = \min\{A, B\}$ and $Y = \max\{A, B\}$. When I put it like that, maybe it's easier to see why $X$ and $Y$ are *not* independent, which is where your attempted solution breaks.

To actually solve the problem, we can try to understand the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$. Suppose $A, B \sim Exp(\lambda)$. For $s \le t$ the joint CDF will be
$$\begin{align}
F_{X,Y}(s,t) &= P[X \le s, Y \le t] \\
&= P[A \le t \text{ and } B \le t] - P[s < A \le t \text{ and } s < B \le t] \\
&= F_A(t) F_B(t) - [F_A(t)-F_A(s)][F_B(t)-F_B(s)] \\
&= \left( 1 - e^{-\lambda t}\right)^2 - \left( e^{-\lambda s} - e^{-\lambda t}\right)^2
\end{align}$$

Then for the joint pdf we get
$$\begin{align}
f_{X,Y}(s,t) &= \frac{d^2}{dsdt} F_{X,Y}(s,t) \\
&= 2 \lambda^2 e^{-(s+t)\lambda}
\end{align}$$

Also, the CDF for $Y$ is $F_Y(t) = F_{X,Y}(t, t)$, so the pdf is
$$\begin{align}
f_{Y}(t) &= \frac{d}{dt} \left( 1 - 2 e^{-\lambda t} + e^{-2 \lambda t} \right) \\
&= 2 \lambda \left( e^{-\lambda t} - e^{-2 \lambda t} \right)
\end{align}$$

Now we're finally ready to plug into the formula for conditional pdf:
$$\begin{align}
f_{X|Y}(x|y) &= \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_{Y}(y)} \\
&= \frac{2 \lambda^2 e^{-(x+y)\lambda}}
{2 \lambda \left( e^{-\lambda y} - e^{-2 \lambda y} \right)} \\
&= \boxed{\frac{\lambda e^{\lambda(t-s)}}{e^{\lambda t} - 1}}
\end{align}$$

Note that the final formula, like all the other cdfs and pdfs computed in this solution, is only valid on the region $0 \le s \le t$. Outside of that region the pdf is 0.